# "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'' message in visual studio running python code

Tags: python

I am confused on what is wrong with my code and I keep getting the error message "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

```
#Lab 5-4 The Bottle Return Program

#the main function
def main():
    endProgram = 'no'
    while endProgram == 'no':
        totalBottles = getBottles()
        totalPayout = calcPayout(totalBottles)
        printInfo(totalBottles, totaPayout)
        endProgram = raw_input('Do you want to end the program?(Enter yes or no): ')   
def getBottles():
    totalBottles = 0
    todayBottles = 0
    counter = 1
    while counter <= 7:
        todayBottles = input('Enter the number of bottles for today: ')
        totalBottles = totalBottles + todayBottles
        counter = counter + 1
    return totalBottles

def calcPayout(totalBottles):
    totalPayout = 0 
    totalPayout = totalBottles * .10
    return totalPayout

def printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout):
    print ('The total number of bottles collected is', totalBottles)
    print ('The total paid out is $', totalPayout)
main()
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I believe its 2. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ea113de-a009-46cd-99f5-65ef0595f937

Comment: If Visual Studio provides such a thick wrapper around the Python interpreter that you can't even tell which version it is (something the interpreter prints out every time it's started), you should really consider using different tools.

Answer (score 2):

The error means exactly what it says: You're trying to use `+` to add a string to an int.

Find the place where this is happening, and cast the string to an integer (if you want to do numeric addition), or the integer to a string (if you want to do string concatenation).

The full exception message, which you didn't include, will specify the precise line.

Answer (score 0):

```
 totalBottles = 0
    todayBottles = 0
    counter = 1
    while counter <= 7:
        todayBottles = int(input('Enter the number of bottles for today: '))
        totalBottles = totalBottles + todayBottles
        counter = counter + 1
    return totalBot
```

todaybottles is a string because the input() function returns the input as a string. totalbottles variable is an integer. you can't add a string to a integer, so you get an error. you should change the value from string to integer by doing this(notice the int function under while loop)